# Filter JSON data by date Angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to filter the following JSON, so that I only load the up and coming fixtures, in other words all fixtures from the current time onwards. But nothing loads, do I have something wrong, maybe the format of the date, not sure.

JSON
http://www.football-data.org/teams/354/fixtures/?callback=JSON_CALLBACK

FILTER

```
angular.module('PremierLeagueApp', [])
.filter('upComingFixtures', function() {
return function (fixtures) {

  var filtered_list = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < fixtures.length; i++) {

    var currentTime = new Date().getTime();
    var fixtureDate = new Date(fixtures[i].date).getTime();

    if (currentTime <= fixtureDate) {
      filtered_list.push(fixtures[i]);
    }
  }
  return filtered_list;
}
});
```

CONTROLLER

```
 .controller('fixturesController', function($scope, $routeParams, footballdataAPIservice) {
    $scope.id = $routeParams.id;
    $scope.fixtures = [];

    footballdataAPIservice.getFixtures($scope.id).success(function (response) {
        $scope.fixtures = response; 
    }); 


});
```

HTML

```
<tr ng-repeat="fixture in fixtures.fixtures | upComingFixtures">
        <td>{{$index + 1}}</td>
        <td>{{teamName(fixture.awayTeam)}}</td>
      </tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe your filter should accept a value and then return true/false to either include that value or not. Something like this

```
    <tr ng-repeat="fixture in fixtures.fixtures |  upComingFixtures(fixture)">

   $scope.upComingFixtures = function(fixture) {

      if(fixture time > current time) {
         return true; // include this
      } else {
         return false; // Don't include this
      }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I forgot to declare the filter in the app.js:

```
angular.module('PremierLeagueApp', [
  'PremierLeagueApp.services',
  'PremierLeagueApp.controllers',
  'PremierLeagueApp.filters',
  'ngRoute','ngAnimate'
]).
```

so all's fine with the code above :) Thanks in any case.